# Typeguard for string in sentence case or title case

Tags: typescript

I am setting the `sameSite` property of a cookie, which needs to have a value of `Strict`, `Lax` or `None` but a package that I'm using has lowercase values for the attribute, thus I need to modify the first letter of the string:

```ts
let sentenceCaseSameSite: "None" | "Lax" | "Strict" | undefined
if (
    (sessionCookie.attributes.sameSite &&
        sessionCookie.attributes.sameSite === "strict") ||
        sessionCookie.attributes.sameSite === "lax" ||
        sessionCookie.attributes.sameSite === "none"
    ) {
        const firstLetter =
            sessionCookie.attributes.sameSite[0].toUpperCase()
        const sentenceCaseSameSite = (firstLetter +
            sessionCookie.attributes.sameSite.slice(1)) as
            | "None"
            | "Lax"
            | "Strict"
    }
```

This works because I've added `as | "None" | "Lax" | "Strict"` but this never feels like the right approach.

Is there a way to capitalise the first letter of the string without losing type safety?

Comment: You can use the built-in utility type [Capitalize](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#capitalizestringtype), but you will still need to do `as Capitalize<type>`

Comment: My code is a little contrived so it is possible to see the capitalised vs uncapitalised types. In reality I don't need to do this as I'm trying to translate between the two types that already exist, but I want to know if I can avoid using `as` to tell the compiler the type of the concatenated string (which loses type safety).

Comment: I have an idea in my mind how to make the first character uppercase without `as`, but it will work only with ASCII, though no idea about the slicing, since it returns a `string`

Comment: Just a side-note, the [draft proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cookie-same-site-00#section-4.1) that incorporates `SameSite` in the cookie spec does says the values are not case sensitive. I'm not sure whether implementing browsers respect this however

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos - didn't realise. Will still need to work around the type errors for now and will capitalise to be on the safe side until it's clear the browsers are complying, but good to know.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code, to take advantage of `Capitalize`, `as` must be used inside `cap` because typescript doesn't know that `x[0].toUpperCase() + x.slice(1)` produces a capitalized type.  The expectation of the Typescript designers was that a user would write a function like `cap` and therefore want a `Captialize` utility to define the return type.

The typeguard for `L` is applied to `x.sameSite`, so it can be safely passed to `cap`.  `sessionCookie` then has the correct type.

[TypeScriptPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAMjAvDARAOwPZqimAfVAGwEMAPXAlAZxACcBLAYxBQG5gAzAVzWfqxj0qcABRUAXMTRgAlOJhVBihAG9gMDTFpQQXWmhgBtdFhwAaFCXIWaDZigC6AOnq9CXACZQqYmewC+nDx8AozEECKk4nAyMGqaWjp6BqSGAAzOIBgAqhDQtADCxFRQIrEA1DCkTlSETKUAjLHFMEUQ9CDEdQBeUAA8cAB8AcBejCTaMIxYNFXyKgrEALZQAModUPK2rgDm+DA8XhyuUB4w-uz0HDAiQqLVVMtrGzIy8ZqEOgreVPxoBRgMABreiwZBhCIPJ7rEBQPwwAD0CJg4GgSlQADlTBRUHAyDiUKs6EwWMBAsBgEA)

```
type L = "none" | "lax" | "strict";
function isL(s:any): s is L {
    return ["none","lax","strict"].includes(s);
}
function cap(x:L) {
    return x[0].toUpperCase() + x.slice(1) as Capitalize<L>;
}
declare const x: { sameSite: string | undefined };
if (isL(x.sameSite)){
    let sessionCookie = cap(x.sameSite); // type is "None" | "Lax" | "Strict"
}
```